# Convert SQL to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to convert this into entity framework

```
Emp
______
EmpID
Fname
Lname
PostID

Post
______
PostID
Position
Select e.Fname, e.Lname, p.Position from Emp e inner join Post p
on e.PostID = p.PostID
```

and bind to DataGridView

Trial:

```
    var query = db.Employees.Include("Position")        // source
   .Join(db.Positions,         // target
      c => c.PosID,          // FK
      cm => cm.PosID,   // PK
      (c, cm) => new { Employees = c, Positions = cm }) // project result
   .Select(x => x.Employees).Where(m => m.Fname.Contains(txtSrchFirstName.Text) && m.City.Contains(txtSrchCity.Text));
   .Select(x => new { x.EmpID, x.Lname, x.Fname, x.Position, x.City});  // select result

     GridView1.DataSource = query1.ToList();
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Employees and Positions table? It's better if you include table relationship in the question also.

Comment: Create foreign key relationship to `PostID` field and you can query directly from `Positions` without using join.

Answer (score 1):

From off the top of my head:

```
var query1 = from e in Emp
             join p in Post
             on e.PostID equals p.PostID
             select new {e.Fname, e.Lname, p.Position};
```

Answer (score 0):

jmcihinney's query is equivalent to your sql query however normally, with EF, you'd try to use navigation properties to access related data so that you don't have to describe the relationships between entities in each and every query.

You only need to write

```
var query = from e in db.Employees
            from p in e.Posts
            select new { e.EmpID, e.Lname, e.Fname, p.Position, p.City});
```

NB

I don't know where City comes from, it's not in your original query but it is in your trial, and secondly, this requires the relationship to be correctly defined (with navigation property) in the model.